# Как можно тримить значения числа с плавающей точкой

Tags: javascript

Как можно при вводе в input значения 12.4567 и зная например что precision у нас 3 -> обрезать число 12.456? Проблема с моим кодом что если скопировать значение 12.4567 в input то пропускает полностью это число и не обрезает, а если вводить то всё норм работает.

```
const precision = 3;
const numbersAfterDecimal = value.split('.')[1];

if (numbersAfterDecimal && numbersAfterDecimal.length > precision) {
    const amount = value.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: @Дмытрык и как это отвечает на вопрос округления до нужного числа детсятичных знаков?

Comment: `Math.trunc(v*1000)/1000`

Comment: Без округления и просто обрезать по Precision

Comment: trunc это не округление, а взятие целой части. если надо учесть произвольное число знаков после запятой, то делить не на 1000, а на Math.pow(10,precision). Либо просто `v.toFixed(3)`, но он округляет

Comment: @teran, если без округления, то конечно по-другому надо.  . П.С - я и не постил ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось решить проблему через substr таким способом:

```
const precision = 3;
const numbersAfterDecimal = value.split('.')[1];
const positionDot = value.indexOf('.');

if (numbersAfterDecimal && numbersAfterDecimal.length) {
   const amount = value.substr(0, positionDot + (precision + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`yourNumber.toFixed(precision)` - Возвращает строку с округлением

`yourNumber.toString().match(/^-?\d*(?:\.\d{0,precision})?/)[0]` тоже вернет строку, но уже без округления

Comment: точки экранировать не забывайте. И лучше тут реплейс тогда использовать, ибо совпадения в строке может и не оказаться.